# Angular 2: Can't bind to 'ngModel' even though FormsModule is imported

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am getting the `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` error, though I have imported the `FormsModule`.

package.json:

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
```

In main app.module:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [App],
  declarations: [
    App
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgaModule,
    PagesModule,
    routing
  ]
```

Here's where I route to the component (pages.routes.ts):

```
import { NewProjectModule, BasicForm } from './new-project/new-project.module';
...
{ path: 'new-project', component: BasicForm },
```

Here is the component module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
import { BasicForm } from './basicForm.component';
...
export { BasicForm } from './basicForm.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, BrowserModule],
  exports: [BasicForm],
  declarations: [BasicForm]
})
export default class NewProjectModule {
}
```

Also imported FormsModule into component just for good measure:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'basic-form',
  template: `
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="directory" placeholder="C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Projects" [(ngModel)]="project.directory">
  `
})
```

Error is thrown on the above template line.

Comment: what is NgaModule? where do you use ngModle? I mean in which module?

Comment: NgaModule is a theme module.  ngModel is used in the module that contains the component.  I have included FormsModule there as well, though I think the main AppModule including should be enough?

Comment: @mtyson template line is in other than app.component.html then add that component in declarations of app.module.ts.

Comment: @Sanket - Can you elaborate?  I'm not quite following.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @johnDisplayClass Sort of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39811149/467240

Answer (score 2):

I spent a long time looking into this, and the I finally realised I made the rookie mistake of not **including the component I was building in the NgModule declarations**

```js
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms"; // <--- import FormsModule 
import { MyModule } from "./components/my-module/my-module.component"; // <--- import your component

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyModule // <--- add your component to declarations 
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgbModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule // <--- add FormsModule to imports
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say exactly what did it, but I completely refactored and the issue is resolved.

Instead of using a component in the routes definition, I used loadChildren:

```
{ path: 'new-project', loadChildren: () => System.import('./new-project/new-project.module') },
```

which pulls in the module.  In the module, I made sure to import FormsModule:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, NgaModule, FormsModule, routing],
```

And now angular is finding NgModel for the form template.

Answer (score -2):

The ngModel is an angular2 directive, 
This directive can be used by itself or as part of a larger form. All you need is the ngModel selector to activate it.

So **no need** to import

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

I think your syntax is correct.

just try by importing the below package

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

If its still not working just chnage the template like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="directory" [value]="project.directory">
{{project.directory}}
```

Or

```
<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="project.directory">
    {{project.directory}}
```

*If its still have the error your problem is with 'project.directory' or some other property of 'input.*

Go through this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html for detail information about ngModel.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Everything I've seen says you must import FormsModule to use NgModel.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html

check this link, in my knowledge there is no need to import{ form module},

you need to import {form module} only to get form directives like as ngControl, ngFormModel etc.